# Transaction getting Timeout using Java SDK

Tags: java-sdk

I'm using the Java SDK for months now but since couple of weeks I'm getting more and more timeouts while launching Payment Operations.

> org.stellar.sdk.responses.SubmitTransactionTimeoutResponseException: Timeout. Please resubmit your transaction to receive submission status. More info: https://developers.stellar.org/api/errors/http-status-codes/horizon-specific/timeout/

Here is the code snippet:

```
Transaction transaction = new TransactionBuilder(sourceAccount, Network.PUBLIC)
                    .addOperation(
                            new PaymentOperation.Builder(destination.getAccountId(), new AssetTypeNative(), amount)
                                    .build())
                    .addMemo(Memo.hash(hash))
                    .addPreconditions(TransactionPreconditions.builder().timeBounds(mTimeBounds).build())
                    .setBaseFee(Transaction.MIN_BASE_FEE)
                    .build();
            transaction.sign(source);

            SubmitTransactionResponse response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);
```

I tried to increase the fees (MIN_BASE_FEE * 2, even *10) but has no effect, I still get Timeouts for the operations.

Any idea why I'm getting so many Timeout errors ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the upper timebound?
For a payment, the upper timebound can be high like 60s or more since the amount you send will probably not change.

The MIN_BASE_FEES are probably too small also, try to use 10000 at least.